# Boundary Case conditions for String Anagrams

Tags: java, data-structures

I trying to write one string Anagram program but stuck while checking the boundary conditions.

I know there are lots of ways and programs available on internet related to String Anagrams using single loops or using collections framework, but I need the solution for my code that how can I involve boundary cases for the code.

```
public class StringAnagram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String str = "abc";
    String strAnagram = "cba";

    boolean areAnagrams = ifAnagrams(str, strAnagram);
    System.out.println(areAnagrams);
}

private static boolean ifAnagrams(String str, String strAnagram) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int count = 0;
    char[] a = strAnagram.toCharArray();

    if (str.length() != strAnagram.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        {
            System.out.println("str.charAt(i) in outer loop :" + str.charAt(i));

            for (int j = 0; j < strAnagram.length(); j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == strAnagram.charAt(j)) {
                    System.out.println("str.charAt(i) : " + str.charAt(i));
                    System.out.println("strAnagram.charAt(j) : " + strAnagram.charAt(j));

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        if (count == str.length()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Code is working fine if I am inputting the input likes -
"abc" or "abcd" where each char in string is occuring only one time, but it fails when input is like "aab" can be compared to "abc" and it will show strings are anagrams.
So, how this condition I can handle in my code. Please advice.

Comment: You could use sorting. I think insertion sort is ok if your letters less than 20.

Comment: But if I write an anagram checker, I'd probably declare 2 arrays in which each hold an another array whose indices are the letters to be checked i.e. `arr[letters['j']];` which is nothing more than a counter. At the final stage I'd compare if the counters match. Highly likely the program's time complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: In lieu of using arrays, you could accomplish this by using `HashMap` data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This may still be wildly inefficient.  Again I apologize for initially overlooking your requirement that no collection frameworks could be included.

```
public class StringAnagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // String str = "abc";
        // String strAnagram = "cba";

        String str = "abcdd";
        String strAnagram = "dccba";

        boolean areAnagrams = ifAnagrams(str, strAnagram);
        System.out.println(areAnagrams);
    }



    private static boolean ifAnagrams(String str, String strAnagram) {

        int count = 0;
        char[] a = strAnagram.toCharArray();
        char[] b = str.toCharArray();

        String alphaString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] alpha = alphaString.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("");

        if (str.length() != strAnagram.length()) {
            return false;
        }


        for (int i=0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
            int countA = 0;
            int countB = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){

                if (a[j] == alpha[i]) {
                    countA++;
                }
                if (b[j] == alpha[i]) {
                    countB++;
                }

            }

            if (countA != countB) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This alternate solution makes use of a string that contains all the letters in the alphabet, and iterates through them to check if both strings have the same count of each letter.  No frameworks this time :)

Comment: You are using Arrays.util function, I already hinted that please try without collections. Its most common answer on internet man, you just copy pasted from there :), Can you advice how in my code I can handle this situation.

Comment: I edited and changed my solution.  It doesn't make use of a framework import anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that it only checks if each character in the first string is present in the second string. There are 2 more conditions you need to consider:

1. If each character in the second string is also present in the first string
2. If character count for each character in the first and the second string matches

Your current solution will return `True` for input of `("aaa", "abc")` while it should return `False`. Implementing the first condition I mentioned above will fix this problem.

After you implement the first condition, your solution will return `True` for input of `("abb", "aab")` while it should return `False`. Implementing the second condition I mentioned above will fix this problem.

Here is a simple way to make this work:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (charCount.containsKey(c)) {
        charCount.put(c, charCount.get(c)+1);
    } else {
        charCount.put(c, 1);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < strAnagram.length(); i++) {
    char c = strAnagram.charAt(i);
    if (!charCount.containsKey(c)) return false;
    if (charCount.get(c) == 0) return false;
    charCount.put(c, charCount.get(c)-1);
}

for (char k : charCount.keySet()) {
    if (charCount.get(k) != 0) return false;
}

return true;
```

Since there are no nested loops, the time complexity is **O(n)**. Even though a Map is used, the space complexity is **O(1)**, since it is guaranteed that the total number of keys will not exceed the number of all possible characters.

This solution is even better than sorting in terms of time and space complexity.